# What's an organized storage solution for Dungeon Tiles?

Tags: organization, tiles

I currently have them in ziploc bags, but I'd like to have a system that keeps them organized and quickly accessible in game.  What have other people used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If they are not too thick you could try [accordion folders](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Globe-Weis-Jan-Dec-Accordion-Open-File-12-Pockets-Brown/14922482?sourceid=1500000000000003142050&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=14922482). That way you can separate them by type (muddy, rocky, crypt... whatever).

Edit: For ease of seeing them without pulling them out. A [Three Ring Binder](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Office-Impressions-3-D-Ring-Vinyl-View-Binder-White/14929441) and [sheet protectors](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Avery-Secure-Top-Sheet-Protectors-25ct/14935271) would work.

Comment: You know, the binder+sheet protector+card protector sheets for smaller tiles seems about ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use a number of boxes reclaimed from boardgame expansions that didn't need them; I have the tiles sorted somewhat into wildnerness, dungeon, city, and so on. Each box has a ziplock bag to contain the little tile bits (i.e. dressing, and small-size tiles). It's not optimal, but it keeps them tidy when put away.